# Download Visual Studio Code extensions behind proxy

Tags: visual-studio-code

Despite setting the `http.proxy` setting, I am unable to download extensions (or browse extensions).

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your solution to the issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found that if I start the program with `--proxy-server=http://myproxy.example.com:3128` then it works.

Comment: Hey, can you please clarify, what you mean to start the program with the proxy command?

Comment: @konstantin change your shortcut and add the --proxy-server... parameter.

Comment: Is. it possible to elaborate more on this. My remote server is Ubuntu, how can i add to the shortcut the proxy server?

Comment: This solution worked for me. Changing the settings.json within VScode did not do anything.

Comment: I'm using VSCodium and I have the same problem. I tried opening it using "codium --proxy.example.com:1234", but the problem persists

Comment: I also tried changing the link directly but this didn't help either (using Ubuntu 18.04)

Comment: It seems that `code-server` used for remote development doesn't support this flag, unfortunately.

Answer (score 5):

The `code-server` used for remote development doesn't support the `--proxy-server` flag.

The workaround I have found is to manually download the `.vsix` extension archive for the extension I want to install. e.g. from here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools there's a "Download Extension" drop down on the right under "Resources" where I can download the extension for the server's platform.

Then, move this archive to the target server. Since I'm using an ssh remote, I just `scp` it over.

Then, install the extension from the archive:

```
~/.vscode-server/bin/<id>/bin/code-server --install-extension /path/to/archive.vsix
```

And this should install the extension. I had to restart the editor a few times before the extension showed as installed in the editor as well.

Comment: Or, if the remote has access to the Internet, you can install the extension directly. For example, to install the [python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) extension, you may run `~/.vscode-server/bin/<id>/bin/code-server --install-extension ms-python.python`